# Canonical form for set of lists

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, data-structures, combinatorics

I am given two unordered sets, each containing m lists of n items. Example for m=4 and n=3:

```
D1 = {[4,2,1], [3,3,1], [4,2,3], [1,2,1]}
D2 = {[3,2,3], [4,2,3], [1,1,3], [4,2,1]}
```

The two sets are considered equivalent if there is a one-to-one correspondence between the elements in their respective lists. In the example above, D1 and D2 are equivalent because there is an assignment (1,2,3,4) in D1 ↔ (3,2,1,4) in D2.

In this example, the items are numbers, but this does not really matter, because I only care about the equivalence relation between two sets and not about the items themselves.

I am looking for a fast way to check if two given sets are equivalent. Rather than performing a backtracking search to find the assignments between items, can the sets be serialized in a unique (canonical) form, so that two sets can be shown to be equivalent if their canonical forms are identical?

**Update:** Even though this problem seems to be intractable in general (see answer below), it turns out that a search with backtracking works well in practice for my data. Below is the pseudocode for my implementation:

```
s = new stack(of level)
x1_x2 = new dictionary(of int, int)
bound_x2s = new set(of int)

function setsEquivalent(d1: set, d2: set) : boolean
    if d1.m <> d2.m or d1.n <> d2.n: return false        
    s.push(new level)
    do until s.size = 0
        m1 = s.size
        m2 = s.top.m2
        if m1 > m
            return true
        elseif s.top.m2 > m
            backtrack()
        else                
            s.push(new level)
            for k = 1..n
                if not try_bind(d1.m(m1)(k), d2.m(m2)(k))
                    backtrack()
                    exit for
    return false

function try_bind(x1: int, x2: int) : boolean
    if x1_x2.containskey(x1)
        return x1_x2(x1) = x2
    elseif bound_x2s.contains(x2)
        return false
    else
        x1_x2.add(x1,x2)
        bound_x2s.add(x2)
        s.top.boundx1s.add(x1)
        return true

procedure backtrack()
    for each x1 in s.top.boundx1s:
        bound_x2s.remove(x1_x2(x1))
        x1_x2.remove(x1)
    s.pop
    if s.size <> 0
      s.top.m2 += 1

record level
    m2 = 1
    boundx1s = new list(of int)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure that your questions are clear. This question is pretty good but lacks some important information. Tell us more about the "objects." Can they be serialized into a canonical form so a (meaningless) order can be imposed on them? Can two objects be tested for equality? Also, what is the meaning of your example? Are you given the definitions of `D1` and `D2` and the "Solution" is the group of assignments that make `D1` equal to `D2`? If so, that seems backwards from your question. If not, please rewrite your example.

Comment: The nature of the objects does not really matter, because I am only interested in expressing what equivalence class a set belongs to. I hope the question is clearer now after rewriting.

Comment: Why not just take the union of the elements in the lists in each set and check the resulting two sets for equality? Exactly how that plays out depends on how you are representing sets and how you are representing lists.

Comment: Because I consider that two lists are only equal if they contain the same sequence of elements (up to renaming of elements in their respective set). For example, {[2,2,2], [4,2,3], [1,1,3], [4,2,1]} would not be equivalent to D1 or D2.

Comment: So you are talking about some notion of isomorphism rather than simple set equality. In general, isomorphism questions are hard since there are n! candidate bijections (given n elements in the underlying sets) and without some sort of structure, it is hard to avoid brute force solutions. My hunch is that this is NP-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at least as hard as the [Graph Isomorphism Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). A directed graph can be represented as a set of lists of length 2, which is a special case of your problem. Furthermore, the directed graph isomorphism problem is known to have the same complexity as the graph isomorphism problem. Thus, a special case of your problem is as hard as the full graph isomorphism problem. The exact complexity of graph isomorphism isn't know. There are no known polynomial time algorithms for it, though it is not conjectured to be NP complete.

Since there is no easy solution to the graph isomorphism problem, I doubt that serialization will provide an easy solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Indeed, for n=2, the problem would be equivalent to graph canonization for directed graphs, so it seems that serialization will not help here.